# How to use Google Assistant responses in DialogFlow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I try to use Link Out Suggestion for Google Assistant response.

[image]

I test my app and:

- If I set DEFAULT response also works DEFAULT response exactly.
- If I set only Link Out Suggestion I have an error that my test app doesn't respond.

What should me do to make work GOOGLE ASSISTANT response exactly, not DEFAULT response?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the Link Out Suggestion, you must include at least one Simple Response. If you have responses in the Default response section, and you have the "Use responses from the DEFAULT tab as the first response" set on (which you do), it will use those as the Simple Response.

If you have it set off, however, you *must* set your own Simple Responses for the Google Assistant. You cannot have just a link out suggestion - you must have text that goes along with it.

Comment: Thank you, I added simple response for google assistant. Now I can use google assistant response without DEFAULT response!
But now I have only GOOGLE ASSISTANT simple response, link out suggestion doesn't display. Can You prompt me please, what did i do wrong?

Comment: You may want to update your question so you make it clear what exactly you are doing now and what it looks like when you test it out. Providing screen shots to help illustrate will greatly help.

Comment: I made new question, can you look it please?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62166313/how-to-use-google-assistant-link-out-suggestion-in-dialogflow