# How to use google assistant link out suggestion in DialogFlow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have two google assistant responses:

- simple response, cause I must to make it for google assistant
- link out suggestion response, which I need to display

[image]

When I test it, a have just simple response.

[image]

Can you prompt please, what should I do to get linked out suggestion response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have sent a screenshot of the speech interactions of your conversation. Suggestion chips are only shown in the visual display section of the simulator. This can be found on the left side of the web page, either under the Suggestion section or in the visual display of your device.

[image]

If you do not see anything on the left side, check if you have set your simulator to a platform that supports visuals during its conversation, for instance:

- Phone
- Smart Display ( Only normal suggestions will show on smart displays)